How to make oauth1.0 request using guzzlehttp
I am trying to connect two magento2 instances through REST API.
I have already created Endpoints.
I am using GuzzleHttp\Client to make request.
How to implement Oauth 1.0 Using guzzlehttp.
Any other solutions also fine.

@Haarish Infant Raj

Install Guzzle: If you haven’t already, you need to install Guzzle via Composer:

composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
2). Create a Guzzle client: Set up a Guzzle HTTP client with the necessary configuration.
3). Obtain an Access Token: Depending on the OAuth flow you're using (Authorization Code, Implicit, Resource Owner Password Credentials, Client Credentials), you'll need to make a request to get the access token.
4). Make an Authenticated Request: Use the access token to make authenticated requests to the API.
Here’s a basic example demonstrating the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant flow with Guzzle:
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

// Step 1: Create a Guzzle client
$client = new Client();

// Step 2: Obtain an access token
try {
    $response = $client->post('https://example.com/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => 'your_client_id',
            'client_secret' => 'your_client_secret',
        ],
    ]);

    $body = $response->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($body, true);
    $accessToken = $data['access_token'];

    echo "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

} catch (RequestException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

// Step 3: Make an authenticated request
try {
    $response = $client->get('https://example.com/api/resource', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        ],
    ]);

    $body = $response->getBody();
    echo "Response: " . $body . "\n";

} catch (RequestException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

Obtain an Access Token:
You send a POST request to the OAuth token endpoint with the required parameters (grant_type, client_id, and client_secret).
The response will contain the access token.
Make an Authenticated Request:
Use the obtained access token to authorize a request to the API by including it in the Authorization header.
Make sure to replace 'https://example.com/oauth/token', 'your_client_id', 'your_client_secret', and 'https://example.com/api/resource' with your actual OAuth token endpoint URL, client ID, client secret, and API endpoint respectively.
This example uses the Client Credentials Grant type; if you need a different OAuth flow (like Authorization Code or Password Grant), the request parameters and URLs will differ.
Thank You!

I want for Oauth 1.0. I will edit my question

Please stop ignoring the website guidelines. The moderators should have warned you by now about putting signatures and taglines in your posts. Also, please don't use ChatGPT to generate content for this or any other Stack Exchange site.
